# Because executing this script gives me this error? Found declare (at char 1) expecting a keyword netezza

Tags: netezza

The script works correctly in plsql and takes a date from the table DATE_ACUM and generates n records in the table DATE_ACUM_FINAL where n is the number that indicates the day of the field ID_DATE with format yyyymmdd example 20190205 will generate 5 records.

```
    DECLARE
              CURSOR cur_dias IS
              SELECT ID_FECHA FROM FECHA_ACUM;
              curfecha FECHA_ACUM.ID_FECHA%TYPE;
              antfecha FECHA_ACUM.ID_FECHA%TYPE;
              ndia integer;
            BEGIN
              OPEN cur_dias;
              loop
                FETCH cur_dias INTO curfecha;
                EXIT WHEN cur_dias%NOTFOUND;
                ndia:= curfecha-FLOOR(curfecha/100)*100;
                  for i in 1..ndia loop
                    antfecha:=curfecha-ndia+i;
                    INSERT INTO FECHA_ACUM_FINAL (ID_FECHA,ANT_FECHA) VALUES (curfecha,antfecha);
                end loop;
              end loop;
                close cur_dias;
            END;
```

Netezza script:

```
        DECLARE
            cur_dias RECORD;
            curfecha FECHA_ACUM.ID_FECHA%TYPE;
            antfecha FECHA_ACUM.ID_FECHA%TYPE;
             ndia integer;
        BEGIN
            FOR cur_dias IN SELECT ID_FECHA  FROM FECHA_ACUM LOOP
                    curfecha := cur_dias.ID_FECHA;
                    ndia:= curfecha-FLOOR(curfecha/100)*100;
                    for i in 1..ndia loop
                            antfecha:=curfecha-ndia+i;
                         INSERT INTO FECHA_ACUM_FINAL (ID_FECHA,ANT_FECHA) VALUES (curfecha,antfecha);
                    end loop;
             end loop;
        END;
```

Error ->found declare (at char 1) expecting a keyword netezza

Comment: curfecha := cur_dias.ID_FECHA; missed ;

Comment: try  FOR cur_dias IN (SELECT ID_FECHA  FROM FECHA_ACUM) for first loop